# How does conda decide where to look for envs?

Tags: conda

I have ran `sudo chown -R $USER` on on `/opt/anaconda` folder in misguided attempt to fix `Permission denied` install errors, and now it refuses to find my envs in `~/.conda`

Instead it only sees the envs installed in `/opt/anaconda/4.2.0`. I tried `chown`ing back to `anaconda` user, but it still refuses to see envs in `~/.conda`. Does anyone know how conda decides where to look for envs/how to fix this?

Comment: Does `conda env list` say your envs are located in the location you indicated?

Comment: yes it does indeed

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems that conda looks inside files other than .condarc to get some of its settings.